# Why is it recommended to use a cloud builder for yarn?

Tags: google-cloud-build

Looking at the source code for the yarn builder for Google Cloud Build I was wondering why it is recommended to use the builder rather than specifying the entrypoint.

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders/tree/master/yarn

Basically

```
steps
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/yarn'
    args:
      - install
```

vs

```
steps:
  - name: node:10
    entrypoint: yarn
    args:
      - install
```

Is it because the cloud builder is registered with the Google Cloud Container Registry which is faster to read from within Google Cloud build?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you are corrected. Indeed, it's recommended because the read from the Container Registry will be faster to be done, using the builder.

As per the code indicates, you referencing directly the Container from yarn, which will make the access faster than using an entrypoint.

Let me know if the information helped you!

Comment: thanks for your reply, I thought so but wasn't quite sure.